# Create a file using special characters as filename

Tags: files, filenames

I have to create such filename, so I can try one pipeline but I am not quite sure how it would happen. So the file's name(s): `;rm *;.jpg` (or `;rm -rf *;.jpg`). The format of the file doesn't matter, I need only the name.

Can you give me the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `touch` command to create empty files. With crazy names like that, it's *essential* to quote them properly.

```
touch ";rm *;.jpg" ";rm -rf *;.jpg"
```

If you create files named like that on *my* machine your life expectancy will be *very* short. :)